# EnableSelection Removes Active Cell Outline

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am a noob with vba (OTJ trained "programmer" if you could be solibertal with the term), but have been using Stack Overflow to answer many of my questions. I have an interesting thing happening with a macro that auto launches when a workbook is opened. I set all the pages to have a password, and have access only to unblocked cells. The code does not seem to restrict cell selection to any page other than the page the workbook opens to. Futhermore, when it DOES restrict cell selection, I know longer have any visual indication of the current active cell, other than what is found in the Name Box (i.e. the cell is not outlined in any way). I have added my code below if anyone has any suggestions. Thank you so much in advance!

(using Excel 2010, on 32bit, Windows-7 machine)

=================================

```
Sub Auto_Open()
'
' PasswordReset Macro
' Resets the password for all worksheets to "physic$"
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L
'
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
        For Each wsh In Worksheets(Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "Baselines"))
        'wsh.Unprotect Password:="physic$"
        wsh.Protect Password:="physic$", UserInterfaceOnly:=True,      DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        wsh.EnableOutlining = True
        wsh.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    Next wsh
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any sheets where **all** the cells are locked?  Stepping through the code, I found I could replicate the behaviour at the point where a sheet containing no unlocked cells is protected.  I.e. if all sheets had some cells unlocked except for "May", the cell outline on sheet "January" would disappear when sheet "May" was set to be protected.

Comment: I also found that the issue is rectified by simply changing to another application and switching back to Excel.  Or even switching between sheets fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

The code above works for me while keeping the cell outline.  You may want to try selecting a cell on each sheet within your loop.

```
wsh.range("A1").select
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a "bug".

Stepping through the code, I found I could replicate the behaviour at the point where a sheet containing no unlocked cells is protected - i.e. if all sheets had some cells unlocked except for "May", the cell outline on sheet "January" would disappear when sheet "May" was set to be protected.

I also found that the issue is rectified by simply changing to another application and switching back to Excel. Or even switching between sheets fixes it.  And that observation led me to a potential workaround.

---

The following amended version of your code will record which sheet was active at the start of the macro, activate each worksheet while the macro is looping through them, then activate the original worksheet at the end.

```
Sub Auto_Open()
'
' PasswordReset Macro
' Resets the password for all worksheets to "physic$"
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L
'
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim wsh0 As Worksheet
    Set wsh0 = ActiveSheet

    For Each wsh In Worksheets(Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "Baselines"))
        wsh.Activate
        'wsh.Unprotect Password:="physic$"
        wsh.Protect Password:="physic$", UserInterfaceOnly:=True,      DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        wsh.EnableOutlining = True
        wsh.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    Next wsh

    wsh0.Activate
End Sub
```